# Adding new column names to use in spread()

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Big picture: I'm trying to set up an export that has one route as a row and columns for each value.

This code: I'm trying to select the top three transfers for each route (using `slice(1:3)` because I need no more than three values. `top_n()` allows for ties). Then, I'm trying to `spread()` to create 6 columns: a name and a pct for each.

If I were to spread the data right now, the names would become columns, but I need to keep the names in the rows (see Desired Output). I want to create the column names as a key column to use to `spread()`. My approach is creating an error. I'm having trouble thinking of another strategy.

Data frame:

```r
# A tibble: 7 x 3
route_shortname transfer_to   pct
<chr>           <chr>       <dbl>
1 A               D           0.5  
2 A               E           0.5  
3 B               F           0.667
4 B               G           0.333
5 C               D           0.111
6 C               E           0.111
7 C               G           0.111
```

Desired output:

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 7
route_shortname transfer1 transfer1_pct transfer2 transfer2_pct transfer3 transfer3_pct
<chr>           <chr>             <dbl> <chr>             <dbl> <chr>             <dbl>
1 A               D                 0.5   E                 0.5   NA               NA    
2 B               F                 0.667 G                 0.333 NA               NA    
3 C               D                 0.111 E                 0.111 G                 0.111
```

Reprex:

```r
library(tidyverse)

sample_data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~route_shortname, ~transfer_to,              ~pct,
  "A",                "D",               0.5,
  "A",                "E",               0.5,
  "B",                "F", 0.666666666666667,
  "B",                "G", 0.333333333333333,
  "C",                "D", 0.111111111111111,
  "C",                "E", 0.111111111111111,
  "C",                "G", 0.111111111111111
)

transfer_to_table <- sample_data %>%
  group_by(route_shortname) %>%
  mutate(key = c("transfer1", "transfer2", "transfer3"))

#> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots): Column `key` must be length 2 (the group size) or one, not 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = read.table(text = "
route_shortname transfer_to   pct
1 A               D           0.5  
2 A               E           0.5  
3 B               F           0.667
4 B               G           0.333
5 C               D           0.111
6 C               E           0.111
7 C               G           0.111
", header=T)

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(route_shortname) %>%
  mutate(id = paste0("transfer", row_number())) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  unite(v, transfer_to, pct) %>%
  spread(id, v) %>%
  separate(transfer1, c("transfer1","transfer1_pct"), sep = "_", convert = T) %>%
  separate(transfer2, c("transfer2","transfer2_pct"), sep = "_", convert = T) %>%
  separate(transfer3, c("transfer3","transfer3_pct"), sep = "_", convert = T)

#   route_shortname transfer1 transfer1_pct transfer2 transfer2_pct transfer3 transfer3_pct
#   <fct>           <chr>             <dbl> <chr>             <dbl> <chr>             <dbl>
# 1 A               D                 0.5   E                 0.5   NA               NA    
# 2 B               F                 0.667 G                 0.333 NA               NA    
# 3 C               D                 0.111 E                 0.111 G                 0.111
```

Comment: Is it possible to use a function here to avoid multiple calls to `separate`? Something like `mutate_at(vars(starts_with("transfer")), funs(...)` or maybe leveraging `purrr`?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to perform multiple `separate` (i.e. in multiple columns). `data.table` package (like the answer below), or `reshape` package could do that.

Answer (score 0):

Though you tagged this question with `tidyverse` packages, here is an option using `dcast` from `data.table` which let's you do the reshaping in one (admittedly long) line.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(sample_data)
dcast(sample_data, route_shortname ~ rowid(route_shortname), value.var = c('transfer_to', 'pct'))
#   route_shortname transfer_to_1 transfer_to_2 transfer_to_3     pct_1     pct_2     pct_3
#1:               A             D             E          <NA> 0.5000000 0.5000000        NA
#2:               B             F             G          <NA> 0.6666667 0.3333333        NA
#3:               C             D             E             G 0.1111111 0.1111111 0.1111111
```

---

You could also use `reshape` from `base R`

```
sample_data <- as.data.frame(sample_data) # does not work with tibbles for some reason
sample_data$idx <- with(sample_data,
                        ave(route_shortname, route_shortname, FUN = seq_along))
reshape(sample_data, idvar = "route_shortname", timevar = "idx", direction = "wide", sep = "_")
#  route_shortname transfer_to_1     pct_1 transfer_to_2     pct_2 transfer_to_3     pct_3
#1               A             D 0.5000000             E 0.5000000          <NA>        NA
#3               B             F 0.6666667             G 0.3333333          <NA>        NA
#5               C             D 0.1111111             E 0.1111111             G 0.1111111
```

In both cases you'd need to rename columns but I that shouldn't be too hard.